# SELECT COM CAST OU CONVERT EM UM ILIKE USANDO SEQUELIZE

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Eu preciso fazer um full-text search usando sequelize, mas quando eu coloco um iLike para procurar um elemento de uma coluna do tipo inteiro ou do tipo data, eu não posso mandar um String, como eu faria um cast para poder pesquisar por esse elemento?

Um exemplo de uma query com Postgresql para exemplificar o que quero fazer usando o Sequelize:

```
SELECT  "Proposta".id,  "Proposta".id_segurado, "Proposta".data_implantacao, "Proposta".data_assinatura, "Proposta".status, "Proposta".numero_proposta,
            "Segurado".documento, "Segurado".nome,
            p1.id, p1.nome, p1.codigo, p1.documento, p2.id,
            p2.nome, p2.codigo, p2.documento
FROM "Proposta"
LEFT JOIN "Segurado" ON "Proposta".id_segurado = "Segurado".id
LEFT JOIN "Produtor" p1 ON p1.id = "Proposta".id_produtor1
LEFT JOIN "Produtor" p2 ON p2.id = "Proposta".id_produtor2
WHERE ((p1.codigo = '8002866' OR p2.codigo = '8002866') 
AND ("Proposta".status ILIKE '%108297494%' OR "Proposta".numero_proposta ILIKE '%108297494%'
     OR CAST("Proposta".data_implantacao AS VARCHAR) ILIKE '%108297494%'
     OR CAST("Proposta".data_assinatura AS VARCHAR) ILIKE '%108297494%'))
```

E isso foi o que eu tentei fazer utilizando Sequelize:

```
const propostas = await Proposta.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { "$produtor1.codigo$": documento_produtor },
                    { "$produtor2.codigo$": documento_produtor },
                ],
                [Op.or]: [
                    {
                        status: {
                            [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        numero_proposta: {
                            [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`,
                        },
                    },
                    db.Sequelize.where(
                        db.Sequelize.cast(
                            db.Sequelize.col("$produtor1.codigo$", "VARCHAR"),
                            { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` }
                        )
                    ),
                    db.Sequelize.where(
                        db.Sequelize.cast(
                            db.Sequelize.col("$produtor2.codigo$", "VARCHAR"),
                            { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` }
                        )
                    ),
                ],
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: Segurado,
                    as: "segurado",
                },
                {
                    model: Produtor,
                    as: "produtor1",
                },
                {
                    model: Produtor,
                    as: "produtor2",
                },
            ]
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

1- A função cast deve receber a coluna e o campo do banco e não a referencia dentro do node, sendo assim o $produtor1.codigo$ não funcionaria.

2- A função cast deve ser chamada pelo sequelize do index.js dentro da pasta models que é criada automaticamente pelo sequelize-cli

então importe

```
const {sequelize} = require("{path}/models/index.js")
```

e chame a função cast deste jeito:

```
sequelize.where(
    sequelize.cast(sequelize.col("produtor1.codigo"),"varchar"),
    { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` }
)
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!